# Restore repository from client files

Tags: svn

I lost the svn repository for a hard disk failure, I reestablished the repository with an outdated backup and i lost some revisions between backups and clients, Is there any way to recover lost revisions from clients?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Clients do not have the full revision history, only the state of the checked-out items as of the last time you ran `svn update`.

You need a more regular, more reliable backup than what you previously had.

Comment: Yes, i made very bad mistake, it's not gonna a happen again thanks